How to confirm SSL certificate expiration date on an API site?
In Microsoft Edge, I can browse to a website and click on the SSL icon in the address bar. From here, I can dig down and see the expiration date for that site.
However, I can find no way to do this for an API website (with no user interface).
I manage several subdomains and have just updated the SSL certificate. But I guess I gave the same name to the new certificate, and I don't see a way in IIS to confirm which of the two certificates is selected for a given site.

 openssl s_client -connect <site:protocol> -showcerts


An essential step is to query certificate mappings stored in Windows HTTP API via netsh,
netsh http show sslcert

Once you know the certificate hash and its association with the site bindings, you can then query certificate stores to know the expiration date. To learn more about the relationship, you can use a tool like Jexus Manager (this tool is open sourced, so you can dig into the code to better understand the relationship between different parts).
Reference
https://docs.lextudio.com/jexusmanager/tutorials/https-binding

To check the SSL certificate expiration date for an API website in Microsoft Edge, you'll need to use tools like OpenSSL as Edge lacks a direct method. In IIS, to confirm the selected certificate for a specific site, navigate to the site's bindings in the IIS Manager, locate the HTTPS binding, and check the certificate details there.
Thanks in advance!

You can use Edge to check the certificate. Just enter the API address in the address bar. You don't need a useful answer from the API, any request will make an SSL handshake, letting you inspect the certificate.
